# Firebase RTDB: Get items types by field

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a lot of child nodes (20K), placed under a single root node, with trip-station data. Each station has a field with a type of the station (String). There can be several stations with the same type. Is it possible to get a list of all types presented in this data bundle of stations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to get a list of all types presented in this data bundle of stations?

No, there is no query that can return unique values. The single option you have is to read all the data, keep a single item for each type, and remove the remaining duplicates. In the case of 20K nodes, that would be some kind of expensive.

What you can do instead is to denormalize the data, meaning that you should create a node of types:

```
db
|
--- types
     |
     --- type1: true
     |
     --- type2: true
```

Each time you add a new station, add the type in this node. Don't bother to check if a type already exists, because if it exists will be overwritten. Besides that, in the Realtime Database, the write operation is free of charge.

Comment: Hi Konstantin. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?